# How can I move tableview section?

Tags: swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I am developing the application with swift. I stored the objection data named Categories. I've added the tableViewImage here and there is no problem here. I want to move the section of the tableview together with the cell, but it does not. The functions I wrote are below. Please help me.Thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(_tableview:UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
let temp = categories[sourceIndexPath.section]
categories[sourceIndexPath.section] =  categories[destinationIndexPath.section];
categories[destinationIndexPath.section] = temp
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method, assigning the position of the section you want to move and the place where you want it to be at the end:

```
table.moveSection(0, toSection: 1)
```

You could also try deleting the section in the IndexSet or appropriate position, subtracting in 1 the number of sections of the table and then reinserting the section and increasing the sections by 1

```
let index = IndexSet(integer: 0)
self.number_sections -= 1
table.deleteSections(index, with: .fade)

let newIndex = IndexSet(integer: 1)
self.number_sections += 1
table.insertSections(newIndex, with: .fade)
```

Comment: Hi Angel, I tried what you said. But the thing I want to do is drag drop and reorder section

Comment: :D I see, you should edit your question to specify that detail